# How Can I Be Certain a Microsoft Dynamics 365 Managed Solution Patch Roll Up Worked As Expected

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a solution for dynamics 365 online that I control as unmanaged in git and deploy to production as managed. We have applied a number of managed patches into production and now want to roll up the changes. Reading [1] the process seems to be that we need to export the a new managed solution and roll up the patches in production to that new solution. How can I be certain that my new full solution hasn't lost anything from the old solution plus patches?

As an example, given I have:

- Managed solution 1.0.0.0 in production
- Patches, 1.0.1.0, 1.0.2.0, and 1.0.3.0 also deployed managed to production

…then how do I obtain a managed version 1.1.0.0 in production that looks identical to the 1.0.0.0 plus patches code?

[1] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/create-patches-simplify-solution-updates

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you may have approached this incorrectly by importing the patches into your target environment as managed solutions, and I'm not sure what your options are.

The correct approach assumes (in my practice) 3 environments:

1. **DEV**. This is where you have your unmanaged solution. You create and export your `patch` solution here
2. **TEST**. You import your patches here and verify everything works. Once everything is working you use the `Clone Solution` to roll your patches into a new major version. You export this new major version as a Managed Solution
3. **PROD**. You import your new Managed Solution here. Because it has a new major version, it overwrites / replaces your existing solution

In your **TEST** environment you should be able to select the "main" solution (i.e. version 1.0.0.0) and then click `Clone Solution`. This will allow you to specify a new major version number (e.g. 1.1.0.0). It will then automatically "roll-up" all the patch solutions - assuming that you created the patches using the `patch` process

From the article you linked

> For a managed solution ... [y]ou
>   **first clone the unmanaged solution (A), incorporating all of its
>   patches and then exporting it as a managed solution (B)**. In the target
>   organization that contains the managed version of the (A) solution and
>   its patches, **you import managed solution (B)** and then execute
>   DeleteAndPromoteRequest or the DeleteAndPromote Action to replace
>   managed solution (A) and its patches with the upgraded managed
>   solution (B) that has a higher version number.